# C# Custom Installer for applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I want to install 3 application using the same installer and add some things like:

- user name and password and to be stored in registry encrypted
- an ip address stored in registry
- serial number also stored in registry encrypted

The first application connect to a device using some predefined messages (one of them contains the username and the password) and receive alerts and alarms.

The second application is a server that receive the message from my first application and send it to a windows form.

The third application is a windows form the display the alerts and alarms from device.

I have to use those 3 applications because it has to be a modular software, the first application changes depending on the device and the windows form (the third application) it's also custom depending on the needs.

I tried using setup project from visual studio but i don't figure it out.

Comment: What _types_ of applications?  Not all installers are created equal and some technologies are better than others depending upon the type of application.

Comment: One application is receiving some data from an external device using ports and sends the data to a server (using async client-server communication), the other application is the async server and the 3rd application is a windows form that show in a table the info that a receive

Answer (score 2):

Try using InnoSetup it is open, it is quite difficult but you have some example you can follow them

[InnoExample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-Installer-for-InnoSetup) made by stfx, it describes how can we develop **Modular InnoSetup Dependency Installer**

it is able to install various dependency , like .net framework, SQL Server ...

And you can customize your messages using multiple languages options.

Answer (score 1):

NSIS and InnoSetup are tradition way in installer creation with known  pluses and minuses.

There is a modern and robust suggestion - Win#
( http://wixsharp.codeplex.com/ ) - flexible and simple solution that allows to wrap Wix internals into C#.  You will be able to write custom actions on native C#, use WinForms and (even) WPF to build installer UI using common .NET practices.

I am old NSIS progammer but highly recommend to take a look on Wix#.

Comment: Is this Win# installers going to execute on a Fresh Windows XP which don't have .NET framework installed on it?

Comment: It allows to install .NET as prerequisite (by building corresponding boostrap .exe, where from additional libraries are installed). But, however, .NET is required in case you are developing UI design on WPF. In other cases (with no UI or, even Windows Forms) .NET is not needed. There is a sly technology - C# scripts are translates into Wix toolset internals (e.g. into databases, conditional checks, custom actions, Wix UI, etc) transparently from developer (but you are able to use "real" C# with full .Net power ).

Comment: Thus, it is a interestingly solution in middle of the low level NSIS coding and modern mouse-clicking combines like InstallAware.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Win32 APIs then you should go with NSIS. It's very flexible than any other Installers for Windows system and an easy to master scripting language. Otherwise, your choice could be WiX (.msi installers), Inno or any others.

Though Wix can be integrated into Visual Studio and you can deploy directly your C# project into it to build an installer, but it has a steep learning curve compared to others.

Just for note: Wix needs to be downloaded and installed manually and It's FREE.